# Javascript objects with properties that are functions details about 'this'

Tags: javascript, object, scope, this

```
var foo = {
  p1: function(){
    return this.p2;
  },

  p2: function(){
    console.log('i am foo.p2');
  }
};
```

I'm trying to do something similar to the example above, however I'm running into an issue where when I invoke:

```
var result = foo.p1();
```

result == 'undefined'

I'm confused about the way 'this' works within object context. Could someone explain where I'm going wrong here?

**EDIT**
more complete example:

```
suite_segments.themis = {

    //don't re-run themis initialization script
    initialized: false,

    /**
     * Initializer for themis product. Returns true if initialization
     * operations were performed, false if not (most likely because 
     * the product was already initialized -- not a fresh navigation)
     */
    init: function(){

            //prevent multiple initializations
            if(this.initialized)
                return false; //did not initialize
            this.initialized = true;

            //operations
            jQuery('#tabs').tabs();


            //init success
            return this.themis_destroy;         
    },





    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *      DESTRUCTORS
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
    /**
     * Function to be invoked if user navigates away from 'themis' entirely. Other
     * sub-destroy type functions will be invoked if necessary when a user switches 
     * between parts of themis
     * 
     */
    themis_destroy: function(){

        console.log('themis_destructor');
        this.initialized = false;

    },
    /**
     * Designed to be overwritten every time a segment of themis is loaded. Will be invoked 
     * ever time a segment of themis is loaded.
     */
    themis_sub_destroy: function(){}


};
```

Comment: Post the actual code that you're trying or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: `foo.p1()` really yields `foo.p2`. Post a more complete snippet.

Comment: I don't know, man, your snippet actually works in JSFiddle. `suite_segments.themis.init();` really returns `suite_segments.themis.themis_destroy`. There must be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your completed example will work as well. With your code, `suite_segments.themis.init()` *will* return the descructor function (or `false`), not `undefined`.

But you have an other problem: the destructor won't work. Read [this excellent overview about the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and you'll see: `this` points to the current context, which is call-dependent. When invoked per `...themis.init()`, the function will be called in the context of the `themis` object - everything is fine. But the function that is returned (`suite_segments.themis.destroy`) won't be called on the object, but (I guess) standalone - and has no chance to set the `initialized` property of the correct object.

In your case, I can recommmend the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context of the returned function:

```
return this.themis_destroy.bind(this);
```

See also [this blog post about "*objects with properties that are functions*" or *the mythof of methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html), which covers exactly your title question, and [this post about `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html).

Answer (score 1):

Doug Crockford has a good [page about private/public/privileged members](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) within objects, and talks about the best practices for defining those members. That might help clear up some of your confusion surrounding the `this` variable.

In your example, however, you must not be showing us something. The return value of `foo.p1` is the function `foo.f2` as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/erSWu/1/

Comment: Although giving the object private "members" by using a constructor could solve the OPs problem, that article is completely useless without further explanations, especially on the `this` keyword (which the article does *not* clarify)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a miner mistake bro...

it should be like this:

```
var foo = {
  p1: function(){
    return this.p2();
  },

  p2: function(){
    console.log('i am foo.p2');
  }
};
```

Comment: No, *that* would return `undefined`, because `foo.p2` doesn't return anything.

Comment: That's not what Casey wants. He wants the *reference* to `foo.p2` to be returned, because in his more detailed snippet `foo.p2` is a destructor to be called later.